# How to set multiple class numbers in one write in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

can you tell my how to set multiple class numbers in one write?
I have `$('.oven_program_01')` class, and .click action. This action will be fire after click at elements with clasess from `$('.oven_program_01')` to `$('.oven_program_12')`. Can you tell me how to write this without repeat this clasess? Something like that: `$('.oven_program_'01-12')` Much thx for help.

Comment: Why do they all have different classes?  Why not give them different ids and have them share a class, or give them all a second class that they can share?

Comment: bc thoes clasess generating automaticly from xml, and have conected with other elements actions :) ... more complicated

Answer (score 2):

Classes are really designed to label "types" of things on your pages.  If you are labeling individual elements then you should use the id attribute.

So for your elements I would set an id of "oven_program_01" to "oven_program_12" and a class of "oven_program" for all the elements.

This way you can select a particular element with:

```
$("#oven_program_01")
```

and select all of the elements of this type with:

```
$(".oven_program")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `Attribute Starts With` selector:

> `[name^="value"]`

```
$('elem[class^="oven_program_"]').click(function(){
  // ...
})
```

Please note that by using this selector, class attributes must begin with `oven_program_` not the other class names.

---

Or [`Attribute Contains Selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/):

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value containing the a given substring. `[name*="value"]`

```
$('elem[class*="oven_program_"]').click(function(){
  // ...
})
```

Comment: But what if the element exposes more than one class? Something like `class="foo bar oven_program_01"`?

Comment: @ŁukaszBorawski You can try the `Attribute Contains Selector`.

Answer (score 1):

Classes, like ID's, can also be used to in JavaScript scripts, but unlike ID's, they can be used multiple times in the same HTML document. This separation of content from presentation is what makes sites powered by CSS more robust, but some don't know the full extent to which they can use classes. Classes can not only be used more than once, but more than one can be used on an element:

i think its not good idea to have different classes, its better use same classes, different id's.

Comment: ok, everybody knows that but i don't want to repeat thoes 'milion' claesses :)

Comment: i think its better to first learn different methods to grab the elements in jquery :) i suggested best practice.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("[class^=oven_program_]").click(....)
```

Although the best thing would be to use TWO classes for you objects, like

```
class="oven_program_01 oven_clickable" 

$(".oven_clickable").click()
```

or better use an ID and a common class.

```
id="oven_program_01" class="oven_clickable"
```

That's the purpose of classes and ids, by the way

Answer (score 0):

```
$('[class^=oven_program_]')
```

This will select any class that *starts with* `oven_program_`.

Need to be more specific?  jQuery does not have a built-in regex selector, but someone made this:

http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/regex-selector-for-jquery/

Haven't used it, but seems like you would do

```
$(':regex(class, oven_program_\d\d?)')
```

Finally, I'm not 100% sure what you're doing but I wouldn't even use a class.  I would do something like `<element class="oven_program some other class names" data-oven_program="12">`.  You can use the same selectors above on data attributes too, if necessary.